# How to get last records of SQL search with grouped names

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
| id | name   | mac               | disk_usage |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
|  1 | simon  | 00::00:00:00:01   | 10         |
|  2 | monica | 00::00:00:00:02   | 10         |
|  3 | andrew | 00::00:00:00:03   | 10         |
|  4 | amon   | 00::00:00:00:04   | 10         |
|  5 | peter  | 00::00:00:00:05   | 10         |
|  6 | rusty  | 00::00:00:00:06   | 10         |
|  7 | simon  | 00::00:00:00:01   | 22         |
|  8 | amon   | 00::00:00:00:04   | 15         |
|  9 | monica | 00::00:00:00:02   | 18         |
| 10 | simon  | 00::00:00:00:01   | 2          |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

When I put for search word "mon" I want this result:

```
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
| id | name   | mac               | disk_usage |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
|  8 | amon   | 00::00:00:00:04   | 15         |
|  9 | monica | 00::00:00:00:02   | 18         |
| 10 | simon  | 00::00:00:00:01   |  2         |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

I am using this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT test.* FROM test WHERE name LIKE "%mon%" ORDER BY id DESC)test GROUP BY name ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But I get this:

```
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
| id | name   | mac               | disk_usage |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
|  4 | amon   | 00::00:00:00:04   | 10         |
|  2 | monica | 00::00:00:00:02   | 10         |
|  1 | simon  | 00::00:00:00:01   | 10         |
+----+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: What you actually want, say in words, please. Do you want the maximum of each group?

Comment: @1000111 As I said in the title, I need last record, not maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation function `max()` by id, then join based on `ID`.

```
select * from test t
inner join 
    (select max(id) id, name
    from test 
    where name like '%mon%'
    group by name) t1 on t1.id = t.id
order by t.id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You cshould use a subquery for max mac group by name and join this to you original table

```
select * from test 
inner join  (
  select name, max(mac) max_mac
  from test  
  group by name 

  ) t on t.name  = test.name and t.max_mac = test.mac
```